# JS: Converting PHP time to a JS Date

Tags: javascript, php

My backend is sending me a time like this:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->format('m-d-Y H:i:s')
```

the value of `$date` is a string like `"01-21-2021 15:25:06"`

Can I use that to create a Date object in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, a simple format change is all that is required:

```js
const dateString = "01-21-2021 15:25:06";

console.log(new Date(dateString.replace('-','/')).toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use JavaScript's Date.parse() function to do this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#description